# How to partial differential of a trace of matrix form?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

How to prove that

$$\frac{\partial \mathrm{Trace}(ABA^T)}{\partial A}= AB+AB^T$$

if $A$,$B$ are square matrices.  Can I write the following:

Let $C=BA^T$.  Then,

$$\frac {\partial \mathrm{Trace}(AC)}{\partial A}+A\frac {\partial \mathrm{Trace}(C)}{\partial A} = C^T + AB = AB^T + AB$$

and what is the answer of  $\frac{\partial \mathrm{Trace}(A^TBA)}{\partial A}$?

Thank you~

Comment: **Hint:** write out the definitions of matrix product, trace and partial differentiation in full. The rest is straightforward calculation.

Comment: Your notation being highly non standard, you should explain the definition of the object $\partial\varphi(A)/\partial A$ for $\varphi:M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ and $A$ in $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$. Or read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(infinitesimal)#Differentials_as_linear_maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the indices. In the formulae above, the doubly repeated indices are automatically summed over, using the Einstein sum rule. Note that ${\rm Tr} M = M_{ii}$ and $(MN)_{ij} = M_{ik}N_{kj}$.

The first derivative of the trace is
$$ \frac{\partial A_{ab}B_{bc}A^T_{ca} }{\partial A_{ij}} = \frac{\partial A_{ab}B_{bc}A_{ac} }{\partial A_{ij}} =$$
$$= \delta_{ai}\delta_{bj} B_{bc} A_{ac} + A_{ab} B_{bc} \delta_{ai}\delta_{cj} = B_{jc}A_{ic} + A_{ib}B_{bj} = (AB^T)_{ij} + (AB)_{ij} $$
so by removing the indices $ij$ again, you see that the "matrix derivative" is $AB^T+AB$. Similarly,
$$ \frac{\partial A^T_{ab}B_{bc}A_{ca} }{\partial A_{ij}} = \frac{\partial A_{ba}B_{bc}A_{ca} }{\partial A_{ij}} = \delta_{bi}\delta_{aj} B_{bc} A_{ca} + A_{ba} B_{bc} \delta_{ci}\delta_{aj} =$$
$$ = B_{ic}A_{cj} + A_{bj}B_{bi} = (BA)_{ij} + (B^T A)_{ij} $$
so the second result is $BA+B^TA$.